# Adjust line height in direct labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, direct-labels

I have a line chart to which I want to add labels. The lables have new lines (`\n`). How do I adjust the lineheight of these labels?  I've tried adjusting the `text` in `theme`, but it has no apparent effect. (I'd like the lineheight to be reduced in this instance).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(directlabels)
tx <- time(mdeaths)
Time <- ISOdate(floor(tx),round(tx%%1 * 12)+1,1,0,0,0)
uk.lung <- rbind(data.frame(Time,sex="male\n(men)",deaths=as.integer(mdeaths)),
                 data.frame(Time,sex="female\n(women)",deaths=as.integer(fdeaths)))
p <- qplot(Time,deaths,data=uk.lung,colour=sex,geom="line")+
  xlim(ISOdate(1973,9,1),ISOdate(1980,4,1)) + 
  theme(text = element_text(lineheight = 0.5))  # this seems to have no effect
direct.label(p,"last.points")
```

Comment: If `mdeaths` is a data-object available from a package, you should offer the correct code to load it. Otherwise you should offer `dput(mdeaths)` .... and any other objects that are missing from this example.

Comment: Thanks. `directlabels` is required.

Comment: Correct code: `data(mdeaths, package="directlabels")`

Comment: You can see that direct.labels is replacing the lineheight value if you set it at 3.5 and then `print(p)` before modifying the plot with `direct.label`.

Comment: Indeed. My question is how to get `direct.label` to take notice of my modification. I'm afraid I'm not seeing your point.

Comment: Looking at the code for `direct.label` and the functions to which it links it appears to me that you will need to rewrite the functions if you want that modification.